# Parsing a txt file

Tags: c, parsing, scanf

I am trying to parse a txt file which contains names in the format:

```
"MARY","PATRICIA","LINDA","BARBARA","ELIZABETH",...
```

This is the code I wrote:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
// Names scores
int problem22() {
    FILE *f = fopen("names.txt", "r");
    char name[100];
    fscanf(f, "\"%[^\"]s", name);
    printf("%s\n", name); // MARY
    fscanf(f, "\"%[^\"]s", name);
    printf("%s\n", name); // ,
    fscanf(f, "\"%[^\"]s", name);
    printf("%s\n", name); // PATRICIA
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    problem22();
    return 0;
}
```

Each alternate call to `fscanf` gives me a name, while the other is wasted in fetching a comma. I've tried several formats, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Can anyone help me with the correct format?

Comment: Looks you code working as you wanted, what you wants?

Comment: You should try strtok() in such case

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: I would like each call to `fscanf` fetch a name.

Comment: @xylon97 Note in `"\"%[^\"]s"` , `s` is not needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the input format string to `"%*[,\"]%[^\"]"` would do what you want:

```
fscanf(f, "%*[,\"]%[^\"]", name);
printf("%s\n", name); // MARY
fscanf(f, "%*[,\"]%[^\"]", name);
printf("%s\n", name); // PATRICIA
fscanf(f, "%*[,\"]%[^\"]", name);
printf("%s\n", name); // LINDA
```

The `%*` just skips the matching input.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant[+1].can you please give us more info  where we can found this info how to make escaping sequence.With scanf or fscanf,shall we use normal PCRE regex with `%*` to escape if match

Comment: @Gangadhar with `%*` it is just the same as with `%s`, only the input is discarded.

Comment: @villekulla note in `%[^\"]s"` s not required

Comment: @villekulla Yes, i was understand that one.  As far I know scanf does not support regular expressions. It has limited support for character classes. I want to know can we use PCRE regex with scanf with `%*`.Like `%*[some_pcre_regex_to_escape_match]`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Yes, `s` it is not required, but it is also not prohibited... I just made the smallest change possible to make the format string of the questioner work... Nothing more was asked :)

Comment: @Gangadhar PCRE regexp are not supported.

Comment: @villekulla It should prohibited in a case! Guess what? Btw why did you post it as wiki?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Yes, you are right, the 's' there shall be removed, but it does not do any harm. Please feel free to improve my answer, for somewhat I did post it as wiki :)

Comment: @villekulla I saw you are new guy but nice contribution on SO, keep it up :)..  To understand behavior of scanf/printf I would like to share [a link with you](http://wpollock.com/CPlus/PrintfRef.htm) (may be you already know). I will correct, but someone serially downvoted me so going sing-off for now :( ...

Answer (score 3):

I always like to use `strtok()` or `strtok_r()` function to parse a file. (either prefer to use some csv library).

But just for fun I written a code may be you like it, I am not posting code in my answer but  check @[codepad](http://codepad.org/AftqXqMb) for output, Works for specific format only.

### Using strtok()

The correct approach looks to me is something like below:

```
int main(){
// while(fp, csv, sizeof(csv)){   
    // First read into a part of file  into buffer
    char csv[] = "\"MARY\",\"PATRICIA\",\"LINDA\",\"BARBARA\",\"ELIZABETH\"";
    char *name = "", 
       *parse = csv;
    while(name = strtok(parse, "\",")){
        printf(" %s\n", name);
        parse = NULL;
    }
    return 0;
} // end while
```

Check [codepade](http://codepad.org/nRxgKJn0) for output:

```
 MARY
 PATRICIA
 LINDA
 BARBARA
 ELIZABETH
```

What I suggest in second code draw a outer loop to read lines from file to a temporary buffer then apply strtok() code like above something like:  `while(fgets(fp, csv, sizeof(csv))){ use strtok code}`

Comment: So you assume the the whole file is read into memory before parsing?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use **fseek()**.

This code works successfully:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int problem22()
{
    FILE *f = fopen("names.txt", "r");
    char name[100];
    int pos = 0, maxnames = 4, n;

    for(n = 0; n <= maxnames; n++)
    {
        fseek(f, pos, 0);
        fscanf(f, "\"%[^\"]s", name);
        printf("%s\n", name);
        pos += (strlen(name) + 3);
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    problem22();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strtok()` 
read entire line and split it into tokens with the delin string `","`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Names scores
int problem22() {
    FILE *f = fopen("file", "r");
    char *tok=NULL;
    char name[100];
    fscanf(f,"%s",name);

    printf("string before strtok(): %s\n", name);
    tok =  strtok(name, ",");
    while (tok) {
        printf("Token: %s\n", tok);
        tok = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }


return 0;
}

int main() {
    problem22();
    return 0;
}
```

Note:    The `strtok()` function uses a static buffer while parsing, so it's not thread safe.  Use `strtok_r()` if this matters to you.

see `man strtok_r`